# How can I search lucene for "John J" and get people like "John Jameson" not just people with John?

Tags: lucene

For reasons out of my control, I must do this with a global search. I've taken converting a search term "John J" into (John AND J), which works for anyone who's last name doesn't start with the same letter as their first.

How can I make the search for "John J" become "find all people who have John and then another, different J in the field"?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using an NGramTokenFilter or something? Looks like a [phrase query](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Terms) is probably what your looking for. Use quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try out Wildcard Query. For example:

```
Term term = new Term("secondName", "J*");
Query query = new WildcardQuery(term);
```

I am assuming you have a different fields for first and second name. You can create a boolean query with a combination of queries for first and second names.

Documentation for WildcardQuery: http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/WildcardQuery.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I'm building out a typeahead input using lucene. So the user will have typed in "John J" so without a heap of logic, I can't simply do J*.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned it is a type ahead input; prefixQuery might help -

```
new PrefixQuery(new Term("lastName","J"));
```

This will return all documents with lastName starting with "J".

To get results where firstName starts with "John" **and** lastName starts with "J", you can have -

```
BooleanQuery.Builder booleanQueryBuilder;
booleanQueryBuilder.add(new PrefixQuery(new Term("firstName","John")));
booleanQueryBuilder.add(new PrefixQuery(new Term("lastName","J")));`
```